# How do i change the resolution in Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: resolution, ubuntu

I just installed Kubuntu 14.04 on my HP laptop, but the resolution is off. Everything is way too big...and when i go to my settings, the only resolution available is 800x600....Can anyone please help me fix that.

Also, i have searched online but have not found anything that helps.

Comment: Please post your question in the Stack website http://askubuntu.com/ (first take a look there if somebody else had the same problem, at first glance it surely looks so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change graphic driver. Unfortunately you provided not enough information to give you correct answer. With what you said I can only suspect that you probably don't have intel build in graphic card. It should work immediately. I assume you have nvidia or ati graphic card.

If yes go to **Settings** > **Repositories** > **Additional Drivers tab** and select the correct driver, and click Apply changes.